# Make a UITextField active on load

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, keyboard-events

I have an app that only has one text field and I want that text field active with the keyboard active when the view loads.

Is there any way to force it?

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it the first responder. See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/06_ImplementingController.html) for a tutorial from Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
[self.myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, you can make it the first responder with

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder

Answer (score 0):

Calling the object to be a **First Responder** will do it. But I spent a few minutes finding out it's best to assign it.. **LAST!**

```
[UITextFeild becomeFirstResponder];
```

If you have an animation UIView for example, assign it **after** the view is drawn.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.9
animations:^{
    UIView.frame = newFrame;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9
        animations:^{}
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UITextFeild becomeFirstResponder];// << Right here..
    }];
}];
```